# How to determine errors in coordinates from SIMBAD error ellipse

Tags: coordinate, simbad

How to determine errors in ICRS coordinates from the SIMBAD error ellipse, please?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By moving the cursor over "**ICRS** coord. *(ep=J2000)*"
you can display a tooltip, which says:

> Syntax of coordinates is : "ra dec (wtype) [error ellipse] quality bibcode" :
>
> - *[error ellipse]* :  measurement uncertainty, on (ra,dec) if the positional angle is 90 degrees, on (majaxis,minaxis) otherwise (in mas at defined epoch in the original catalogue),
>   position angle (in degrees North celestial pole to East)

So I read **`[ 3.69 1.67 90 ]`** as an uncertainty of:

- 3.69 milliarcseconds (0.246 milliseconds of time) east-west
- 1.67 milliarcseconds north-south

Comment: Thus, is it 1.0250000000000001e-06 get that would be displayed in Gaia Archive?

Comment: @ElenaGreg The [SIMBAD position](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=eps%20Ori)'s bibcode link indicates that it's from Hipparcos. Different observing programs have different error ellipses. I think ε Ori is too bright for Gaia anyway.